# Getting NetBeans to accept MiniJava

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have some pre-made MiniJava code that I'd like to use in NetBeans, but I don't think such packages exist in NetBeans to let me use it. How can I get it to work in NetBeans, as this is something I HAVE to use for my project?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.cambridge.org/resources/052182060X/),

> MiniJava **is a subset** of Java.

Given that statement, all of your MiniJava programs should work in Netbeans.

Comment: Right I understand that, but there are certain imports that are not being accepted for example: import visitor.VisitorAdapter;
import staticanalysis.SymbolTable;
import syntaxtree.*